# Display images in UITableview

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, swift3, haneke

I'm trying to display images from api in the tableview but I get no images or anything. ImageTableViewCell has the outlet to the image only.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import Haneke

class  SlideViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableview : UITableView!

 var images = [String]()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.dataSource = self

    getJSON()


}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 0
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return images.count
}



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageTableViewCell


    let url = URL(string: images[indexPath.row])

    cell.images.hnk_setImage(from: url!)

    return cell
}




func getJSON() {

    let url =  "http://localhost:8000/api/hello"
    request(url ,  method: .get,  encoding: JSONEncoding.default  )
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {
                //Handle the results as JSON
                do{
                    if let albums = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: []) as? [String: Any],
                        let pics = albums["pic"] as? [Any] {

                        self.images = pics as! [String]

                        for kick in pics {
                            self.images.append(kick as! String)

                        }

                    }

                }catch {
                    print("Error with Json: \(error)")
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableview.reloadData()
                }

    }
  }
   }

   }
```

Any help will be appreciated. I tried many methods but this seems to be simple and easy to follow up

Comment: in this line your app crashed ?                         self.images.append(album["pic"] as! String)

Comment: yes you are right @KKRocks

Comment: what does this line :                         self.images.append(album["pic"] as! String)

Comment: append string or appends array ?

Comment: trying to append the URLs to 'var images'

Comment: try to replace : self.images.append(contentsOf: album["pic"]) ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have at least one section to show.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Comment: No need for numberofSections methods. Tableview having already one section by default.

Comment: @leo0019 This is completely wrong answer if you are having only one section then there is no need of this method

Comment: The only thing i did is to show the error on his code. If he wants, he can delete this function, but both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON response is `Dictionary` not `Array` and its contains `pic` array inside of it. So type result of `jsonObject(with:options:)` to `[String:Any]` instead of `[[String: AnyObject]]`

```
do{
    if let albums = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: []) as? [String: Any], 
         let pics = albums["pics"] as? [Any] {

        images = pics.flatMap{ $0 as? String }
    }
}catch {
    print("Error with Json: \(error)")
}
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I tried but it gives me an error and I printed album 


 '>["pic": <__NSArrayI 0x6000002873f0>(
http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg,
http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg,
http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg,
http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg,
http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg,
http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg,
http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg
)
]
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)'

Comment: print(images] = [] no images displayed !

Comment: still no images

Comment: @leo0019 Don't add code here in comment edit your question with your code Also have you check edited answer

Comment: @leo0019 If you are getting images in array then check its url is it valid or not.

Comment: @leo0019 Don't forgot to accept my answer so it helps others too with the same problem to get response from JSON

Comment: SUCCESS: {
    pic =     (
        "http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg",
        "http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg",
        "http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg",
        "http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg",
        "http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg",
        "http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg",
        "http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg"
    );
}

Comment: this is what images return

Comment: @leo0019 Are you getting object in your images array or not, IF not Edit your question With your actual JSON not add in comment here

Comment: @leo0019 Are you getting object in array or not? also check my edited answer and initialise image array that way no need to write for loop.

Comment: I printed images again and it's an empty array. the table is also empty after using your code @NiravD

Comment: @leo0019 Why are still using for loop edit your question you current code also remove the comment that having code and response from answer and add that in your question

Answer (score 1):

Check below code

```
var images = [String]()

func getJSON() {

    let url =  "http://localhost:8000/api/hello"
    request(url ,  method: .get,  encoding: JSONEncoding.default  )
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {
                //Handle the results as JSON
                do{
                    let albums = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [[String: AnyObject]]
                    print(albums)
                    if let pics = album["pic"]
                    {
                       for album in pics
                       {
                            images.append(album)
                       }
                    }

                }catch {
                    print("Error with Json: \(error)")
                }
                self.tableview.reloadData()

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: cannot subscript a value of type [[String : AnyObject]] with an index of 'String' 

this error appears next to if let pics = albums["pic"]

Comment: @leo0019 What is the output in response? can you please comment here?

**{ response in**

Comment: SUCCESS: {
    pic =     (
        "http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg",
        "http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg",
        "http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg",
        "http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg",
        "http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg",
        "http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg",
        "http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg"
    );
}

Comment: @leo0019 Try to convert your response using

let albums = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(response, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)

Comment: cannot subscript a value of type [[String : AnyObject]] with an index of 'String' this error appears next to if let pics = albums["pic"]

Comment: still says annot subscript a value of type [[String : AnyObject]] with an index of 'String'

Comment: @leo0019 You are using swiftyJSON right ?. Just try to add below line after API success response and check what is output? 
print(JSON(response))